# How to delete "\r\n", but only in certain sections of my text?

Tags: regex, editpad

How can I delete all `\r\n` characters (to convert it to just 1 line) just for the `<out>...</out>` block of the text below using regex?

```
<nx1>home</nx1>
<nx2>living</nx2>
<out>text one
text continues
and at last!</out>
<m2>dog</m2>
```

The final result for this sample of text should be:

```
<nx1>home</nx1>
<nx2>living</nx2>
<out>text one text continues and at last!</out>
<m2>dog</m2>
```

Comment: I'm using EditPad Pro regex engine;
I tried to use lookarounds but without success; sth like:
(?<!</out>)\r\n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for

```
(?<=<out>(?:(?!</?out>).)*)\r\n(?=(?:(?!</?out>).)*</out>)
```

and replace all with a single space. Tested on EditPad Pro 7.3.1. Make sure you select the "Dot" option, so the dot also matches newlines.

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=               # Look behind to assert that there is...
 <out>             # an <out> tag before the current position,
 (?:(?!</?out>).)* # followed by anything except <out> or </out> tags
)                  # End of lookbehind
\r\n               # Match \r\n
(?=                # Look ahead to assert that there is...
 (?:(?!</?out>).)* # any number of characters ahead (except <out>/</out> tags)
 </out>            # followed by an </out> tag
)                  # End of lookahead
```

Comment: thanks a lot man; it worked just fine; Can you describe the pattern?

Comment: EditPad pro team can make an amazing software by adding the possibility of using secondary, tertiary, ...patterns; I mean with a simple pattern like `\Q<out>\E.+?\Q</out>\E` we highlight the excerpt text for continuing the search and after that, within the highlighted text just a simple find of `\r\n` and replace it with a space!

Comment: Upvoting for the explanation ... I hate regex